# How to send character to arduino using bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on a project, I have a problem with sending string to bluetooth module when I send image send success but when I send string not showing the bluetooth option showing gmail share it and google drive

Here is my Java code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
//intent.setType("image/*");
String content="b";
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,content);
startActivity(intent);
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> appslist=pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);

if(appslist.size()>0){
    String packagename=null;
    String classname=null;
    boolean found=false;

    for(ResolveInfo info:appslist){
        packagename=info.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(packagename.equals("com.example.app")){
            classname=info.activityInfo.name;
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found){
        showToast("Bluetooth havn't been found");
    }else{
        intent.setClassName(packagename,classname);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have used this code for sending string .... and it works for me

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);

        }
    });
```

after click this button open a dialog box with multiple option you can choose bluetooth... Thank you

Comment: now its working but it convert into html file did arduino read html file content??? I am using HC 05 bluetooth module